# How to create Editable Dropdown List with Dictionary Option using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, dhtml

Eg:-- When I type "A" all the elements starting with A should be displayed... If "B" then elements with B....etc)

Ex:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLocation" style="width:140px" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Value="1" >India</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" >India - Hyderabad</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">South Africa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="4">Australia</asp:ListItem>       

    </asp:DropDownList>
```

javascript :

```
function DisplayText()
{
 var textboxId = '<% = txtText.ClientID %>'; 
    var dropdownListId = '<% = ddlLocation.ClientID %>'; 
    document.getElementById(textboxId).value = document.getElementById(dropdownListId).value; 
    document.getElementById(textboxId).focus(); 
}
```

code behind :

```
ddlLocation.Attributes.Add("onChange", "DisplayText();");
```

Regards
ravi,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to use jQuery autocomplete or [ExtJs ComboBox](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html)